# Weird error when testing a Rails + AngularJS app with Rspec and PhantomJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec

I have an app that lists tickets. It uses AngularJS. Here's the controller action:

```
def index
  @tickets = apply_scopes(@tickets)
  response.headers['x-total-count'] = @tickets.total_count
  response.headers['x-per-page'] = Ticket.default_per_page
end
```

The Angular controller (Coffeescript):

```
$scope.fetch = ->
  Ticket.query($scope.search).then (response) ->
    $scope.tickets    = response.data
    $scope.totalCount = response.headers('x-total-count')
    $scope.perPage    = response.headers('x-per-page')
$scope.fetch()
```

I'm using [angular-rails-resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource) to fetch the records. Everything works smoothly if I test by hand.

Here is the spec:

```
let(:user) { create :user }

scenario 'User lists tickets', js: true do
  login_as user, scope: :user
  ticket = create :ticket, user: user

  visit root_path
  click_on 'Support Requests'

  expect(page).to have_content(ticket.subject)
end
```

When I run this spec, I just get the regular Rspec failure message because the condition was not met, but it should have:

```
expected to find text "ticket 000" in...
```

I figured it had something to do with concurrency and Capybara not waiting for Angular to fetch and display the records. Then I went ahead and added a `sleep 2` right above the expectation just to test that. When I do it, I get a different error:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
  One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

  Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\">\n<HTML>\n  <HEAD><TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE></HEAD>\n  <BODY>\n    <H1>Internal Server Error</H1>\n    undefined method `split' for 1:Fixnum\n    <HR>\n    <ADDRESS>\n     WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.3.3/2016-11-21) at\n     127.0.0.1:54674\n    </ADDRESS>\n  </BODY>\n</HTML>\n","status":500,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/tickets","params":{},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Content-Type":"application/json"},"data":{}},"statusText":"Internal Server Error "}
  Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\">\n<HTML>\n  <HEAD><TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE></HEAD>\n  <BODY>\n    <H1>Internal Server Error</H1>\n    undefined method `split' for 1:Fixnum\n    <HR>\n    <ADDRESS>\n     WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.3.3/2016-11-21) at\n     127.0.0.1:54674\n    </ADDRESS>\n  </BODY>\n</HTML>\n","status":500,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/tickets","params":{},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Content-Type":"application/json"},"data":{}},"statusText":"Internal Server Error "}
      at http://127.0.0.1:54674/assets/application-713835b1641be632b29f7502c00a879e171bca5d6d06a5f264afcd819c123e76.js:14363
```

Here is my stack:

- rails (5.0.2)
- capybara (2.12.1)
- poltergeist (1.13.0)
- rspec-core (3.5.4)
- phantomjs 2.1.1

Additional info:

- If I output something right before ending the controller action, it gets outputted. The execution is going through the entire action;
- If I `console.log` something right before fetching tickets, it's outputted as well. However, the Promise is not being resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue was with my pagination headers (`x-total-count` and `x-per-page`). Converting them to String does the trick. The weird part is that it was working OK in development, but not in test environment. So, if anyone has this issue in the future, the solution in my case was:

```
def index
  @tickets = apply_scopes(@tickets)
  response.headers['x-total-count'] = @tickets.total_count.to_s
  response.headers['x-per-page'] = Ticket.default_per_page.to_s
end
```

Notice `.to_s` being called when assigning the headers.